# Does the battle between the flesh and the spirit ever get easier?

Tags: sin, spirituality, sanctification

I am 24 years old. I have been a Christian for 5 years, but was raised in church. For the last two years I have been trying my best to walk out this faith to the best of my ability. I am not trying to brag (honestly), but I spend about 45min-1hour reading my Bible a day. I pray for a long time each morning and periodically throughout the day. I am trying my hardest to live a life that honors God, but I am finding that there is a dichotomy within me. My entire being wants to honor God but it also want to enjoy the pleasures of sin. I have begged God to free me from the sin that has bound me. I just want to know if there will ever be a point in my life that I will not be bound by a particular sin and will be able to walk in freedom.

Comment: Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

Comment: Questions of this kind are not suitable for a platform like Stack Exchange, which is academic in nature, nor for SE-Christianity, which is focused on _comparative_ Christianity and is not a 'Christian Site' as such. Feel free to look at my own profile, and at my website (link on the profile). I felt much the same as you seem to, when I was your age. (I am now in my seventies and I assure you : it is still a daily battle to be spiritual in the midst of an evil world.)

Comment: Romans 7:24-8:4.  Take heart brother!  The Apostle Paul himself had the same struggle.  The struggle is proof of the new life.  You are in the process of being delivered and He will not fail who has called you.  Trust in the Lord with all your heart and do not lean on your own understanding.   Do not grow weary in well doing, in due time you will reap.

Comment: A similar question was put to an 80-year old hermit. He answered: " I am slowly progressing to that state of perfect harmony between the spirit and the flesh. I will let you know when I am there."

Comment: Hear St. Philip Neri (in Maxims and Sayings): ``We ought to fear and fly temptations of the flesh, even in sickness, and in old age itself, aye, and so long as we can open and shut our eyelids, for the spirit of incontinence gives no truce either to place, time, or person.'' Life on earth is a warfare (Job); and Philip Neri again: "Paradise was not made for poltroons."

Comment: Jesus said the spirit is willing but the flesh is weak. And that's exactly what your going through.  Don't give up keep fighting, use scripture as a weapon, we are at war. The devil and his angels will stop at nothing to prevent us from receiving the crown of life

Comment: No human (excepting Jesus, and opinions differ on Mary) has ever been without sin. It's simply not possible. Not for Peter, not for Paul, and not for you or me. What is possible, is to be free from sin - to not let it hold you back. Seek forgiveness, and aim for perfection, but realise that you can never get there alone.

Answer (score 3):

For people for whom there is no battle between the flesh and the spirit, then such people remain spiritually dead in their sins. But for Christians, this truth applies:

> "And you hath he quickened [made alive], who were dead in trespasses
> and sins. Wherein in time past ye walked according to the course of
> this world, according to the prince of the power of the air, the
> spirit that now worketh in the children of disobedience... But God,
> who is rich in mercy, for his great love wherewith he loved us, even
> when we were dead in sins, hath quickened us together with Christ, (by
> grace ye are saved)." Ephesians 2:1-5 A.V.

Christians are set free from slavery to sin. Sin is no longer their master (Matthew 23:8). But until this miracle of grace is grasped and believed, our tendency to sin will preoccupy us and keep dragging us down. A Christian perspective is to stop looking to self, or to others, but to keep our eyes fixed on Jesus, the author and finisher of our faith. (Read Hebrews 12:1-2.)

The apostle Paul explained the dilemma (which he fully understood, personally).

> "Knowing this, that our old man is crucified with him, that the body
> of sin might be destroyed, that henceforth we should not serve sin.
> For he that is dead is freed from sin. Now if we be dead with Christ,
> we believe that we shall also live with him. ...Likewise reckon ye
> also yourselves to be dead indeed unto sin, but alive unto God through
> Jesus Christ our Lord. Let not sin therefore reign in your mortal
> body, that ye should obey it in the lusts thereof." Romans 6:6-12 A.V.

It's largely about how you view matters, and who you believe. The deceiver would try to keep you down, thinking you are still gripped by sin, when God tells you that you have been liberated from slavery to sin - that Christ is now your master. You look to, and listen to him, not your own feelings, or self, or whispers of the deceiver. Yes, all Christians know times when they sin, but they confess to God and repent, and he gives them grace to rise above that episode. Well, if they believe him. If they doubt him and think he hasn't actually liberated them from slavery to sin, or that his loving forgiveness is limited, they are hardly going to make much headway in Christian living, are they?

We walk by faith, not by sight, which is why we must keep looking unto Jesus. We must believe the promises of God and rejoice in his liberation of us. When we stumble, we must turn in faith to God's loving forgiveness and patient perseverance with us in making us more Christ-like. We stop looking inwardly at ourselves, or around us at this sinful world's allurements, but look up. But if you think that you are still bound by sin, you have fallen for Satan's lies. The shackles of sin have been smashed. Walk away, in faith. ***It will never be easy***, but once our eyes are focused properly on Christ, we will see more clearly that we ***can*** do that.

Comment: Up-voted +1. _For a just man falleth seven times, ***and riseth up again***: but the wicked shall fall into mischief._ Proverbs 24:16.

Answer (score 2):

**Victorious Life** The verses in the comment above are of help in keeping a true perspective of the Christian life with all its personal and interpersonal struggles. (Romans 7:24-8:4) Paul's statement at the end of his life is appropriate: *I have fought a good fight. I have finished my course.*

It is noticed that one area of Christian living was left out in the introduction to this question: **interaction with fellow Christian brothers**.  One does not have to go through life's struggles *alone*.

We are admonished in the Epistles to...admonish one another...confess our sins one to another...pray for one another...exhort one another...honor one another...etc. Since we are all *members one of another* in the Body of Christ, we draw strength from one another as we minister to each other!!! A prophetic word...a ministry of deliverance...a discerning of spirits...etc...all ensure our Victory in this life over the "world, the flesh, and the Devil."

Add to this the grace of Christ, the empowerment of the Holy Spirit, and the love of the Father, and we all can live like the Bible, hermeneutically interpreted, says we can live.

The battle, according to the Bible, is not fought according to just our efforts alone; but whether or not it gets *easier* **it does get bearable**.

The Christian religion is remarkably different from manmade philosophies of human enrichment, or world religions started by men who are now dead and gone. Christianity is a religion where the Bible informs us of a **relationship with the living God** who actively interacts with us as we follow Christ...and who compassionately interacts with our human struggles...and Who empowers us with His Holy Spirit to live the Christian life (Acts 1).

Answer (score 2):

Mathew 26:41

> The spirit is indeed willing but the flesh is weak.

That best describes what your are experiencing. Trust me, every believer undergoes this struggle daily because of

Ephesians 6:12

> For we do not wrestle against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the cosmic powers over this present darkness, against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly places

And the way out is to take up the sword of the spirit which is the word of God

Ephesians 6:13

> Therefore take up the whole armor of God, that you may be able to withstand in the evil day, and having done all, to stand firm. Stand therefore, having fastened on the belt of truth, and having put on the breastplate of righteousness, and, as shoes for your feet, having put on the readiness given by the gospel of peace. In all circumstances take up the shield of faith, with which you can extinguish all the flaming darts of the evil one; and take the helmet of salvation, and the sword of the Spirit, which is the word of God

This struggle is to be expected as spiritual agents in high places will attack us through temptations where they deem us to be weak in the flesh. God urges us to arm ourselves with the sword of the spirit which is the word of God.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does get easier. I am not a mind-reader but having once been a young man, I suspect sexual sin is a big one for the OP (who is 25). Sexual drive diminishes with age, and so this type of sin becomes less of a temptation as natural urges diminish.

Also, if the person is not married and "honoring God" means refraining from fornication, it should get easier once a man has a wife. Paul deals with this question in 1 Cor. 7:

> 8 To the unmarried and the widows I say that it is good for them to
> remain single, as I am. 9 But if they cannot exercise self-control,
> they should marry. For it is better to marry than to burn with
> passion. 10 To the married I give this charge (not I, but the Lord):
> the wife should not separate from her husband...

Putting it more positively, Genesis 2:24 and Matthew 19:5 both say:

> A man shall leave his father and his mother and hold fast to his wife,
> and they shall become one flesh.

**Conclusion**: Sexual sin runs deep in human nature. But sex is also at very core of God's first blessing: "Be fruitful and multiply."  Temptations related to sex do not disappear with age, but they do diminish.  Being surrounded by a loving family provides important protection. But in the end, everyone still sins. For all types of sin, confidence in God's grace is a key element in Christian faith.

Answer (score 1):

A priest who I knew from youth and later in campus ministry who has recently become my pastor again. After many years of campus ministry, he's came back to parish life with a rather scary realization that as soon as you get to a point where you can deal with sins of the flesh, that were prevalent in the young adults he was ministering to, the sin of avarice takes root.

Fortunately, the cure for both of these, is found in the the Gospel, Mark 9:29, these demons can only be driven out by prayer and fasting. Keeping yourself spiritually poor, doing good works, also help - the simplest way to do this, as the priest I mentioned often would say is, have a large family.

---

In my personal experience, and this is borne out in recent years by the results that men have had in groups like Exodus90, is that

1. Having an accountability partner and a support group (of people of the same sex as you)
2. Eliminating distractions like Internet, social media and cellphones
3. Praying at least 20 minutes per day
4. Avoiding alcohol and overeating
5. Periodic fasting and mortification
6. Tempering use of video games and television

and if none of that works

7. Cold showers

---

Frequent confession, even if you fall again, causes you to really hate sin.  That is a good thing. Sins of the flesh, are ones that seem bad, but are the easiest to forgive.  Dante doesn't even put those who commit them too far down in Hell - not that that is a comforting thought.  Lastly, realizing that God loves you no matter what is incredibly important.  We're all being tried through fire at St. Peter would say.